# How to set the publish interval for topology metrics in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm, stream-processing

While Apache Storm offers several metric types, I am interested in the **Topology Metrics**, (and *not* the Cluster Metrics or the Metrics v2. For these, a consumer has to be registered, for example as:

```
topology.metrics.consumer.register:
 - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
   max.retain.metric.tuples: 0
   parallelism.hint: 1
```

See also the [docs](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Metrics.html).
Unfortunately, these metrics seem to have a **fixed reporting interval** of 60s. For the Cluster Metrics, an interval can be configured, but I can`t find an option for the Topology metrics, even when looking in the source corde of storm.

So: **How to configure the reporting rate for Storms Topology Metrics?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the right place, I found the related configuration:
`topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs: 10` is they way to specify that interval in `storm.yaml`.